# PHP json_encode() and Javascript JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to get data from server in JSON. The data set is very huge and has multi-level nesting. I use arrays. And some keys inside array are JSON strings (i need to store these strings inside database, in order to create JS objects from those strings later).

```
    Array(
    'key1'=> 'value1',
    'key2'=> 'string in JSON format', // json_encode('key2_value that may contain russian symbols', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
    'key3'=> array(
        'key1'=> array(
            key1=> 'string in JSON format'
        )
    )
)
```

The nesting of elements may be arbitrary and any element may contain string in JSON format.

I encode this huge array in JSON, using php `json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` function. I use second param because data may contain russian symbols (i need to search some of those strings later). After that i receive data...

1 step:

Decode all array with JSON strings using JS JSON.parse() function.

2 step:

Save some JSON strings in database columns and after create JS objects using JSON.parse().

But some strings may contain disallowed JSON characters, in particular '\r'. And when i try to parse this string using JSON parse, i can get JSON.parse error for now in second step. But in theory it may occur also in first step.

But PHP json_decode works Good! JS JSON.parse works Bad!

Does anyone have any idea and suggestions? (Please don't forget, when i use json_encode in main array, nested json strings that may contain russian symbols also escaped - slashes, "" i.e).

Comment: So, don't use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Unless you're dealing with a very broken browser, you shouldn't have problems with `JSON.parse` on fully-encoded data. And if you do, you could just use a placeholder, like `~~~r`. You would replace `\r` with the placeholder before running `json_encode()`, then replace the placeholder with `\r` after running `JSON.parse()`. Depending on what you mean by "very huge," that shouldn't cause too bad a performance penalty.

Comment: 1 question: 
Ok. But '\r' it's one of disallowed characters. My data set is near 500 kB size. And special symbols inside main array in json strings escaped again.

2 question:

I write mobile android application using phonegap. I use sqlite database. If i insert data, that may contain russian symbols without JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE... If i will search in database russian symbols, will i have problems?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really follow your comment. I understand that a literal carriage return is not valid in JSON; that's why you need to encode it. I'm not sure why you're saying that encoding it is a problem. JSON.parse should correctly interpret the encoded data.

Comment: Ok... Let's i try explain... I will not use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE... I receive data with russian symbols... parse it...

If i will paste usual strings in database it will be good! But if i paste JSON strings that contain russian symbols... I get in my database column that contain next row: '\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434'. And I CANT USE SEARCH in database!!!!! But if i parse it and print it will be ok... But i NEED ALSO IN SEARCH!!!

Comment: This is still unclear. Are you using `JSON.parse` or not? Are you saving encoded JSON to your database, or the parsed JSON? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understand me... I found 2 solutions of my problem!!!!!!!

1. I encoded with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE filter Main Array, that contain Internal elements in json format with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE filter.

(internal elements will store not parsed in database)

I print my json row in browser, after that copy it and try to parse it in console. It parsed successfully. But when i tried to parse internal properties values in json format, i got parse error in special character positions.

I receive this row in my app and it parsed GOOD, including internal properties values in json format!!!

2. I can don't use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE filter.

I parse Main Array. Paste usual strings that contain russian symbols in database. I can use search in database. But if i'll paste json strings in database with russian characters it will be pasted like  '\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434' and i CAN'T USE SEARCH.

My solution it's - JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('JSON string')) before paste record in database. In this case it will pasted correctly and i can use search.